# how to know if the request is ajax in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

anybody how can I know if the request is ajax ? (I'm using jquery for ajax)

Comment: You could also use Fiddler to watch the requests. You will learn a lot by doing this.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

All AJAX calls made by jQuery will have a header added to indicate it is AJAX. The header to check is `X-Requested-With`, and the value will be `XMLHttpRequest` when it is an AJAX call.

Note that AJAX requests are normal GETs or POSTs, so unless you (or your AJAX library like jQuery) are adding an additional header in the request, there is no way to know for certain whether it is AJAX or not.

Comment: @Omu: `Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]` or similar. Check MSDN. Headers are **always** related to requests.

Answer (score 186):

There's also the `Request.IsAjaxRequest` if you're using a later version of MVC. I don't have version 1 anymore so I can't say if it's in version 1.

If you need this check in Global.asax.cs try this:
`new HttpRequestWrapper(Request).IsAjaxRequest()`

Comment: @BuildStarted I need this check in Global.asax.cs so this won't help me

Comment: @Omu: Depends on which event of the global.asax.cs. This bool property does the same thing internally that RedFiler suggested. And do mind that headers are **always related to requests**.

Comment: `IsAjaxRequest` is an extension to `HttpRequestBase` so it should be available everywhere that the `Request` is available.

Comment: @BuildStarted is not available in Application_Error

Comment: Your sure? Did you try using HttpContext.Current.Request?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's because it's outside of MVC and doesn't utilize `HttpRequestBase`. I haven't had a need for that so I didn't look too deeply. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: new HttpRequestWrapper(Request).IsAjaxRequest();

Comment: BTW: If you are inside custom authorization filter use this to get IsAjaxRequest method on Request: filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest

Answer (score 50):

It works for me in ASP.NET MVC 3

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
     // ajax request handled
}
```

Comment: This is not available in Application_Error

Comment: This is not available in Application_BeginRequest

Comment: In Global.asax: `new HttpRequestWrapper(Request).IsAjaxRequest()`