# Ensure MVC3 action is only ever loaded using JavaScript by hosting site

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 webpage that has some JavaScript that loads some content into a div via  a jquery load command. It looks like this...

```
 $('#divContetn').load('/home/getContent')
```

This is called on a call-back after some other JavaScript is executed.
This code is visible in the page source.

My question is this, is there a way to ensure that calls to this url only come from the webpage and not from someone entering the url in a browser themselves?

Ideally I want to stop users getting this url from the page source and then using it to load just the content into a browser themselves.

The div load has to be done from JavaScript due to the nature of call-back that its loaded after.

Does anyone have any ideas around this?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any attribute relating to AJAX to be set for ASP.NET MVC controller actions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558758/is-there-any-attribute-relating-to-ajax-to-be-set-for-asp-net-mvc-controller-act)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never be able to hide the URL from users. At best, you can increase the effort users will have to put in to get the URL. Even if you manage to hide the URL from the source (by escaping it with JavaScript or maybe retrieve the URL via AJAX), the user can still find out what the URL is by simply using a tool like Fiddler. Or the browser built-in debugging tools, if avaiable.

It is possible to server-side ensure that the URL is only navigatable when the user makes an AJAX call, by placing this attribute above the action method(s):

```
public class AjaxOnlyRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">Information about the action method.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

But, again, that's increasing the effort the user has to put in.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the request was *probably* made with an ajax call by testing for `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864179/how-to-know-if-the-request-is-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)).

This should stop "normal" users from accessing the page directly. But it's easy to forge an HTTP request that contains the headers to make your server believe it's an ajax request.

As a general rule: always assume that anything in a client request can be forged and manipulated. Don't trust anything coming from a client. Especially don't base any security related functionality on any request value or browser feature (except for login credentials and similar, of course).