# How to distinguish whether the call is ajax or not and display the page accordingly in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Let's say I have a default project in MVC. I change the `About` link to be an Ajax form so that it only loads that part of the page. And of course I change the method to return `PartialView('About')` instead of `View('About')`. However, the problem arises when a user types in and goes to a link called `localhost:port/Home/About`. Now it loads about part but without the layout (without css, js, menu bars, etc.)! How can I prevent him from going into such page? Or maybe display an error page instead? Or even redirect him to go to `View('About')`? Options are endless, but how to know that the call was in a "wrong" way?

Comment: Possible duplicate [how to know if the request is ajax in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864179/how-to-know-if-the-request-is-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Why do you care? If the user types in that link, then he deserves what he gets.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Interesting point of view!

Comment: Consider: if the user doesn't like the result of entering that URL, then chances are he won't do that again. So why spend development time on something that won't happen very often and which won't have a detrimental effect in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ChildActionOnly` attribute to the controller method so MVC will not let user call it `directly via http://localhost:port/Home/About`

Comment: Very interesting! Sounds promising! Will definitely try that one when I'm back from work :)

Comment: What will then happen with the request? Where will it redirect?

Comment: Nowhere. This URL will not be mapped to the controller action since it is marked with a `ChildActionOnly` attribute. However it would be possible to use `Html.Action(..)` helper to render the partial content, and it will work as this call is qualified as a child of another action that is being executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in your action method if a request is ajax or not with

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

and take whatever action you need based on this.

This checks if the X-Requested-With header has been set to XMLHttpRequest by the calling client.

[Detecting IsAjaxRequest() with ASP.NET MVC and JQuery Form Plugin / File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681563/detecting-isajaxrequest-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-form-plugin-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

as @Zabavsky it is seems like a duplicate...

another (very simple) solution may be to just seprate the methods. you anyway have seperate views. so the ajax call will trigger AboutAjax() and render the partialView and About() stays as is.